# Having difficulty in loading .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've saved both my python and kv file in the same folder but the program is unable to load it implicitly using the app name. I've tried using Builder.load_file() to load it explicitly but it results in a file not found error.
The only way it works is if i use the Builder.load_string() function but it makes the code tough to manage and also very badly organized. I'd really appreciate some help fixing this error.

Answer (score 0):

- maybe you can check whether your app class name match your .kv file
  e.g.

.py

```
class MyKivyApp(App): # <-- here you should name your .kv file as mykivy , it comes from the class name "MyKivyApp" without the "App"

    def build(self):
        ...
```

so the .kv file name will be mykivy.kv

- or you can try `kivy.lang.Builder.load_string()` in .py , it just like the .kv but in the form of string ...
  e.g.

.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

kivy.lang.Builder.load_string(
'''
#:kivy 2.0.0

<MyApp>

    Button:
        text: 'Helo World !"
        size: root.size

''')

class MyApp(Widget):

    pass


class mykivyApp(App):

    def build(self):

        main = MyApp()

        return main
```

sth like this